# jqgrid search condition not showing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to figure out how to use search function in jqgrid 4.6, basically I'm doing the same thing as here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58357/Using-jqGrid-s-search-toolbar-with-multiple-filter

But in the search panel nothing is showing in the condition, there should be 'equal' or 'contain' which I can select :
[image]

Here is my code, did I miss anything?

```
 function showGrid() {
    $('#ListMessagesGrid').jqGrid({
        caption: paramFromView.Caption,
        colNames: ['EB_USER_MESSAGE_ID', paramFromView.MESSAGE_INFO_IDENTIFIER, paramFromView.MESSAGE_INFO_TIMESTAMP,
          paramFromView.MESSAGE_PARTY_FROM, paramFromView.MESSAGE_PARTY_TO, paramFromView.MESSAGE_COLLAB_SERVICE,
        paramFromView.MESSAGE_COLLAB_ACTION, paramFromView.MESSAGE_COLLAB_AGREEMENTREF, paramFromView.MESSAGE_COLLAB_CONVERSATION_ID],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'EB_USER_MESSAGE_ID', index: 'EB_USER_MESSAGE_ID', width: 80, hidden: false, key: true, search: false },
                    { name: 'MESSAGE_INFO_IDENTIFIER', index: 'MESSAGE_INFO_IDENTIFIER', width: 600, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] } },
                    { name: 'MESSAGE_INFO_TIMESTAMP', index: 'MESSAGE_INFO_TIMESTAMP', width: 450 },
                    { name: 'MESSAGE_PARTY_FROM', index: 'MESSAGE_PARTY_FROM', width: 200 },
                    { name: 'MESSAGE_PARTY_TO', index: 'MESSAGE_PARTY_TO', width: 200 },
                    { name: 'MESSAGE_COLLAB_SERVICE', index: 'MESSAGE_COLLAB_SERVICE', width: 450 },
                    { name: 'MESSAGE_COLLAB_ACTION', index: 'MESSAGE_COLLAB_ACTION', width: 300 },
                    { name: 'MESSAGE_COLLAB_AGREEMENTREF', index: 'MESSAGE_COLLAB_AGREEMENTREF', width: 350 },
                    { name: 'MESSAGE_COLLAB_CONVERSATION_ID', index: 'MESSAGE_COLLAB_CONVERSATION_ID', width: 650 }
        ],
        hidegrid: false,
        multiselect: true,
        pager: jQuery('#ListMessagesPager'),
        sortname: 'EB_USER_MESSAGE_ID',
        rowNum: paramFromView.PageSize,
        rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
        sortorder: "desc",
        width: paramFromView.Width,
        height: paramFromView.Height,
        datatype: 'json',
        caption: paramFromView.Caption,
        viewrecords: true,
        autoencode : true,
        mtype: 'GET',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            userdata: "userdata"
        },
        url: paramFromView.Url
    }).navGrid('#ListMessagesPager', { view: false, del: false, add: false, edit: false },
       { width: 400 }, // default settings for edit
       {}, // default settings for add
       {}, // delete instead that del:false we need this
        {
            closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true,
            closeAfterSearch: true
        }, // search options
       {} /* view parameters*/
     ).navButtonAdd('#ListMessagesPager', {
         caption: paramFromView.DeleteAllCaption, buttonimg: "", onClickButton: function () {
             if (confirm(paramFromView.DeleteAllConfirmationMessage)) {
                 document.location = paramFromView.ClearGridUrl;
             }
             else {
                 $('#ListMessagesGrid').resetSelection();
             }
         }, position: "last"
     });
};
```

**Update**

I found something :

For some reason all values in aoprs array are undefined, so the drop down list not getting populated, is there anyway to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the demo (as JSFiddle for example), which reproduces the problem? If you requires loading the data from the server then you can use `url: "/echo/json/"` provided by JSFiddle. See and example here for examle: http://jsfiddle.net/andm1299/14/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it works in JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/andm1299/16/ but in my application the operator just not showing...

Comment: do you sure that you included `i18n/grid.locale-en.js` before `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` in the application which have the problem?

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Comment: You are welcome! I posted the same information in my answer. I recommend you to upgrade to free jqGrid 4.10.0, where you will have no such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you sure that you included `i18n/grid.locale-en.js` before `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` in the application which have the problem? It's the typical error in the case.

I recommend yot to try to use more recent version of jqGrid. I develop for example [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). It's the fork of jqGrid based on jqGrid 4.7: the latest version available under MIT and GPLv2 licenses. Free jqGrid are provided also under MIT and GPLv2 licenses. The main file `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` (or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`) already **includes** English locale `i18n/grid.locale-en.js`. So one need to include locale file only in case of usage other language. Free jqGrid contains a lot of additional enhancements which I described in wiki and readmes to every version. If you want to use free jqGrid in internet application that I recommend you to use URLs from CDN. See [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) article for details.